# Create GUI apps

Tags: c, user-interface

I've been studying and experimenting on c language with c99 standard for almost 3 months,and everything the whole book i read only taught me how to program in DOS(console) but not in terms of GUI,I know any pro might say i should continue stick to programming in DOS so that i could learn the essence of the language without the need to focus on creating GUI,which could make learning less hassle,but i just wonder if i wanted to create GUI apps ,what thing should i learned??Don't worry i would finish learning the basic and everything before proceed to GUI,for time being i just curious about it and wanting to ask.Thank you.

Comment: What platform are you programming on?

Comment: The first thing to learn is punctuation.

Comment: @David Ah, yes.  The almighty period operator.

Comment: After punctuation we can move on to paragraphs. I know I'm being flippant, but if you can't spend the time to format your question to make it readable for us, why should we spend the time to help? And if you don't take pride in laying out the words you write, how will you succeed as a programmer? Take a look at the care and attention that every single high rep member of Stack Overflow demonstrates in their writing here.

Comment: @David Heffernan: Some people (http://www.escapistmagazine.com/videos/view/zero-punctuation) have made a living ignoring it...

Comment: Thanks for the teaching,i would remember it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, if you're primary concern was learning to code GUI's... You may have chosen the wrong language!

If you're willing to consider C++, you should look at Qt. wxWidgets is also pretty good.

If you really have to stick to C, take a look at GTK+.

Answer (score 2):

First, its **CLI** as in *Command Line Interface* not DOS.

Second GUI programming is different in patterns and requires a lot of Operating System knowledge to be mastered, e.g GUI programs are usually event oriented and threaded but CLIs are usually sequential and single threaded.

If you're familiar with C and C++, I Suggest using Qt SDK which is fairly easy to use, has a thorough help system and has IDEs for almost any purpose.

Since GUI programming is very platform-dependent, General C books dont bother talk about it.

Comment: I can't agree with the "Operating System knowledge" comment. While it's true that all GUIs are event based, and some are thread based, that's not "Operating System". That's just some advanced programming techniques that have nothing to do with operating systems.

Comment: Well Bryan to be precise, its totally operating system (i.e platform) dependent. But in Advanced Programming you face libraries that wrap around OS API, So Basically its OS knowledge and OS API

Answer (score 1):

C isn't a good language for gui development. The language and its standard libraries don't include any gui support. Unless you want to build your own user interface framework from the ground-up, you should use an existing framework - and these are invariably object-oriented. Therefore my advice would be to extend your C skills by learning C++.

On Windows, [MFC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d06h2x6e%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) is a good C++ framework. Although it is a bit dated there is still good tool support and lots of resources on the web.

On Linux/Unix you could try [Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/products/) or [wxWidgets](http://www.wxwidgets.org/), which are cross-platform and support Windows too.

If you insist on using only C then AFAIK your only choice on Windows is the [win32](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383749%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) api. I'd strongly advise against this, though, as it requires a lot of effort to produce even very simple interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

It depends, if you are likely to want complex gui's, with cool effects and animations then you could create a rendering window (like games use) and use a renderer like SDL or OpenGL

On windows, the win32 API with gdi is standard (although I personally hate using it)

Comment: Who said anything about graphics? The question was about GUI. You don't need to know any serious GDI to write a Windows GUI.

Comment: You need to know how GDI works though, or you'll be completely in the hands of your RAD tool. Hacking complete GUIs in raw GDI is indeed a pain, but very educational.

Answer (score 0):

If you plan on working with any form of Windows programming, then you should get the book "Programming Windows" by Charles Petzold, aka the Windows bible. Among other things, it involves the "raw" GUI programming of Windows, ie all the things going on behind the scenes of RAD tools like Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

You really don't want to do GUI development in C.  Even with a decent framework, you'll have to deal with callbacks and memory management issues out the wazoo.  The amount of code you have to write for a "simple" program is roughly an order of magnitude larger for a GUI-driven program than for a CLI-driven one.

It's not *hard*, it's just a royal pain in the ass.

C's ideal for a non-graphical backend or server; graphical client, not so much.